# Different password recovery code received from Facebook

Tags: account-security, facebook

After a long time, I tried to login in to Facebook just to find that I forgot my password. So, to generate new password I used the 'forgot password' option in which a security code to reset password will be sent to my email. I have two emails for account recovery and I received mail on both email address. But both code was different. Is it possible?

Comment: it is possible that different codes are sent to different emails to track which email/code combo is used and not abused.

Comment: Their security part is a disaster. One friend was never able to recover password since they did not sent it towards e-mail and there was no phone number assigned. Instead, it was asked to recognize occasional friends he did never practically met.

Comment: Similar thing happened to me. I set up the two-step verification but was not getting SMS. So, I emailed them and they asked me to provide necessary documents for identification.